# Passing arguments on logout

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I'm working on Symfony5.

I want, in some cases, to logout the user, redirecting him to the login page and displaying on this page the reasons why he has been logged out.

To achieve that, I use a classic "logout" redirect route, which then automatically redirect to the login page.
I tried to put data in the user's session, but the session is cleared on logout so it's empty when it get to the login page.

Here is an extract of my controller function launching the logout process :

```
//... some code to put data in the session
return $this->redirectToRoute('app_logout');
```

And an extract of my security.yml :

```
        main:
        anonymous: true
        lazy: true
        provider: app_user_provider
        logout:
            path: app_logout
            target: app_login
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
```

Do you have any idea how I can do this ? Ideally it would be forcing Symfony to let the data in the session but maybe there are some other ways.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it would help if you could precise what is the technology used.

Comment: I'm working on Symfony5.